# IMU frame to body frame

Tags: 3d, rotations, kinematics, rigid-transformation

I am just wondering how do we transfer IMU readings to Body frame? Especially, linear speed and acceleration.

In following diagram, the IMU is mounted on one of the surfaces of the body (you can imaging it to be a bot, vehicle, drone, or etc.). The center of the vehicle is at Body (green) point in this diagram, and it is on a different surface of the body. Both IMU and Body point are on a rigid body which moving in an inertial frame.

Any hint is highly appreciated. I'd really appreciate if there are some references. Thanks!

[image]